# Why does the United States government utilize random selection (a "lottery") to determine eligibility for an H-1B visa?

Tags: united-states, immigration, visa

According to my understanding of the H-1B application process, applicants must be selected for further consideration by random selection (a "lottery").

Why doesn't the US consider *all* applicants that meet the requirements for an H-1B?

Comment: For clarification, are you asking about the reason the policy was set this way (a historical question - still on-topic, though) or current arguments for/against changing this policy?

Comment: As with all immigration channels, there is a limited quota available each year, and the quota for F1-B visas is stricktly depending on the domestic need of the US. Then, for equal opportunity for all, the lottery system seems the best and fair.